# Synonym for dissolve as the meaning of emotion?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What are the synonyms for "dissolve" verb when it is defined as the following?

> emotion - dissolve into/in laughter/tears etc - to start laughing or
>   crying:
>
> She dissolved into fits of laughter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing an online search? When I search for "dissolve" on Google, for example, the first entry reads (entry 1, part 2):

> **subside uncontrollably into** (an expression of strong feelings)
>   (*She suddenly dissolved into floods of tears.*)
>
> synonyms:  burst into, break into, collapse into, break down into; be overcome with
>
> informal: crack up
>   (*a timid child who was always the first to dissolve into tears*)